# How to set an indentifier for multiple background processes?

Tags: linux, process, ps, background-process

I'm creating a custom game server and I have a .jar file to run it. I need to launch multiple game servers on a single virtual machine(like 15). I found, that I could just run them like this:

```
java -jar server-1.0.jar &
```

but then when I type `ps`, I only see `PID`, `CMD`, `TTY` and `TIME`. How could I identify which is server 6, which is server 9 and etc.? What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for example the `-f` switch to have `ps` display more information. See `man ps`:

> **`-f`**              does full-format listing. This option can be combined with many other UNIX-style options to add additional columns. It also causes the
>                          **command arguments to be printed**. When used with `-L`, the NLWP (number of threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be added. See the `c`
>                          option, the format keyword args, and the format keyword comm.

Comment: thank you! This way I could easily see configuration params for the server. Also, is using plain `&` recommended for such a thing?

Answer (score 5):

You can take note of the `pid` of a background job right after you launch it:

```
command & pid1=$!
command & pid2=$!
```

`$!` is the pid of the last launched background job.

Using tools that search for a pid by the attributes of the process
in a script or program is ill-advised.

A process should always keep track of its children. If you go down the `ps`/`pgrep`... route, you risk killing (=signalling) innocent victims (=processes that aren't your own but which accidentally matched your query).

---

You also run that risk if you aim at the right pids, but those pids aren't your children. A `pid` slot is reserved until the process dies and its parent `wait`s on it (only the parent can `wait` on a process). If a `pid` isn't yours, it may have died and been waited on between the time you learn the `pid` and the time you signal it. Then you could be aiming at an innocent victim (a race condition).

Comment: Even if you don't remember shell does and `jobs -l` (lower-ell) includes pid and commandline for all living children. And unlike most(?) `ps` it doesn't by default truncate display of long commandlines, which fairly often happen with Java programs like `java -cp one.long.jar:another.long.jar:more.long.jars... -Dfoo.bar.propertyname=value -Danotherproperty=anothervalue -Dmanymore... -Xmsthis -Xmxthat -etc -etc -etc  finally.the.interesting.classname and-maybe-app-args`